# Friends and template classes

Tags: c++, templates

How can i compile the below code without changing the status of int data?

```
template<typename U>
void Test(U);

template< class T > 
class B {
    int data;
    public:
    friend void Test<>( T );
};

template<typename U>
void Test(U u) {
    B < int> b1;
    b1.data = 7;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char i;
    Test(i);
    system("PAUSE");    
    return 0;
}
```

The above code causes a compiler error, because `b1.data` is private in `Test` with `U = char`.

Comment: Currently there's no output. What is the expected behavior? What's wrong?

Comment: @aman: What do you think you are doing by writing `friend void Test<>( T );` ?

Comment: Neil, can u pls let me know why am flagged for mod attention?

Comment: @Neil @Aman accounts merged.  No worries.

Comment: You created a new account and they were merged by a moderator.

Comment: To stop being marked down, try to explain what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: @Aman you have to log in under your user account http://stackoverflow.com/users/416112/aman-saleem

Comment: @Prasoon: You might want to read http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/templates.html#faq-35.16

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are befriending `Test<U>` to `B<U>` (for the same U), but you are trying to access the internals of a `B<int>` from a `Test<char>` (different U).

It would probably be simplest to make any Test friend of any B.

Answer (score 0):

This compiled using VS2008. Not sure if it conforms to the standard.

```
#include <cstdlib>

template<typename U> void Test(U);

template< class T > class B {
    int data;
    public:
    template <typename U >  friend  void Test(U);
};

template<typename U>
void Test(U u){
    B < int> b1;
    b1.data = 7;
    }
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char i;
    Test(i);
    system("PAUSE");    
    return 0;
}
```